# Cloud Natural Language API Python script error (Client object has no attribute create_rows)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to create  a script that feeds articles through the classification tool of the Natural Language API and I found a tutorial that does exactly that. I was following this simple tutorial to get an intro into Google Cloud and the Natural Language API.

The end result is supposed to be a script that sends a bunch of new articles from the Google Cloud Storage to the Natural Language API to classify the articles and then save the whole thing into a table created in BigQuery.

I was following the example fine, but when running the final script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify-text.py", line 39, in <module>
    errors = bq_client.create_rows(table, rows_for_bq)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'create_rows'
```

The full script is:

```
from google.cloud import storage, language, bigquery

# Set up our GCS, NL, and BigQuery clients
storage_client = storage.Client()
nl_client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
# TODO: replace YOUR_PROJECT with your project name below
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project='Your_Project')

dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset('news_classification')
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)
table_ref = dataset.table('article_data')
table = bq_client.get_table(table_ref)

# Send article text to the NL API's classifyText method
def classify_text(article):
        response = nl_client.classify_text(
                document=language.types.Document(
                        content=article,
                        type=language.enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT
                )
        )
        return response


rows_for_bq = []
files = storage_client.bucket('text-classification-codelab').list_blobs()
print("Got article files from GCS, sending them to the NL API (this will take ~2 minutes)...")

# Send files to the NL API and save the result to send to BigQuery
for file in files:
        if file.name.endswith('txt'):
                article_text = file.download_as_string()
                nl_response = classify_text(article_text)
                if len(nl_response.categories) > 0:
                        rows_for_bq.append((article_text, nl_response.categories[0].name, nl_response.categories[0].confidence))

print("Writing NL API article data to BigQuery...")
# Write article text + category data to BQ
errors = bq_client.create_rows(table, rows_for_bq)
assert errors == []
```

Comment: You appear to be using code designed for an older version of the library. The `create_rows()` method was [deprecated in version 0.29](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/changelog.html#id26).

Answer (score 3):

You are using [deprecated methods](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/changelog.html#interface-changes-breaking-changes); these methods were marked as obsolete in version 0.29, and removed altogether in version 1.0.0.

You should use `client.insert_rows()` instead; the method [accepts the same arguments](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/4657/files):

```
errors = bq_client.insert_rows(table, rows_for_bq)
```

Comment: ♦ Oh wow that makes a whole lot of sense. I guess the tutorial I found was a little outdated. I am still fairly new to even Python, but due to my job I really want to look into Google Cloud, which has been really overwhelming so far. Thanks for the quick reply I will try to adapt my code :)